# Converting local time to Zulu time in order to compare times

Tags: python, mysql, datetime

I have a DB with time entries formatted as follow:

```
2018-11-05T08:58:00Z
```

I'm trying to generate SQL queries to compare "now()" with the time in the DB to determine which row(s) to return.

I'm battling to "convert" my local time (now()) to an equivalent time format so that I can use < or > operations against the DB values.

Additionally, I am not sure if the problem has two parts. The example fo the time above is not in a "Datetime" field in MySQL but stored simply as TEXT, leaving me to suspect that I would need to "convert" the DB entries into another format first?

Comment: Hint: `Str_to_Date()` . Still, Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Are all your "time entries" text strings ending in `Z`? That is, are they all in Zulu time?

Comment: Hi O.Jones. Yes, they all end with a "Z"

Comment: @Madhur Bhaiya - thank you, I will try to play with your recommended use of Str_to_Date() - I suspect I will need this when converting the existing text entries in the DB to Datetime.

Answer (score 1):

The following code, using the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html) module, works for me (tested in Python 3.6):

```
import datetime

value = "2018-11-05T08:58:00Z"
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(value, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
# Result is: datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 5, 8, 58)
```

This will convert your string values to `datetime` instances, which you can then compare to `now()`. The values that get created should be *naive* (meaning they have no associated timezone information).

However, if you are sure that `now()` for you is not UTC (aka Zulu time), you may need to do a conversion. This could be possible if, for example, you are using Django's `timezone.now()` and your configured timezone is something other than UTC. In this case, I might convert the result of `now()` to UTC, so you only have to convert one value. The [pytz module](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) can easily handle this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Check this :

```
import time

time = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')

print(time)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Answers are *far* more useful when they contain some details in addition to a link. Please make an [edit] to your answer.

Comment: K.Efkas - if I try your code, I get a:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/PyCharm/Dijkstra.py", line 14, in <module>
    currentDT.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%Z') #Reformat it
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: @Monty leave `currentDT` as the original string, don't convert it to a float